# Custom checkbox not transitioning

Tags: css, checkbox, css-transitions

So I got this CSS Custom Checkbox but transitions doesn't seem to work on it. I didn't make the code tho, I got it from [here](https://codepen.io/Vestride/pen/dABHx).

Here is my slightly modified version:

```css
.checkbox {
  position: absolute; 
  opacity: 0; 
}

.checkbox + label {
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 0;
}

.checkbox + label:before {
  content: '';
  margin-right: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: text-top;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background: #ccf2ff;
 border-radius: 6px;
 box-shadow: 0 0 0 3px #99e6ff;
}

.checkbox:hover + label:before {
  background: #80dfff;
}
  
.checkbox:focus + label:before {
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
}

.checkbox:checked + label:before {
  background: #33ccff;
}
  
.checkbox:disabled + label {
  cursor: auto;
}

.checkbox:disabled + label:before {
  box-shadow: none;
  background: #ddd;
}

.checkbox:checked + label:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: 5px;
  top: 9px;
  background: white;
  width: 2px;
  height: 2px;
  box-shadow: 
    2px 0 0 white,
    4px 0 0 white,
    4px -2px 0 white,
    4px -4px 0 white,
    4px -6px 0 white,
    4px -8px 0 white;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}

.checkbox, .button, input, select
{
 -webkit-transition-duration: 0.2s; 
 -moz-transition-duration: 0.2s;
 -o-transition-duration: 0.2s;
 transition-duration: 0.2s;
}
```

Every other transition works fine, it's just the checkbox thats the problem. Am I missing something here? Or is there something wrong with the code that's making transitions not work? Please help me.

Comment: The demo won't work unless you also post the HTML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are applying your custom checkbox style to the `:before` pseudo element of the `label` tag so you just need to apply the transition to that also:

```
.checkbox, 
.button, 
input, 
select, 
.checkbox + label:before
{
    -webkit-transition-duration: 0.2s; 
    -moz-transition-duration: 0.2s;
    -o-transition-duration: 0.2s;
    transition-duration: 0.2s;
}
```

Comment: Oh it was just that simple! Thanks!